# Putting AWS cloudfront in front of ec2 throws 502 error

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to add SSL to my EC2 instance that hosts my API's in a node.js server by:

1) Provisioning a certificate from Certificate Manager
2) Putting Cloudfront in front of my EC2 instance
3) Adding record set in Route53

Before I actually added the record set in Route 53, I made a GET request via postman to my health check api

```
GET cloudfrontdistro.cloudfront.net/health
```

And the response was a 502 with the message

```
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a
configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
```

Relevant details about my Cloudfront distro:

- I used a Custom SSL Cert - the one that I got from ACM)
- TLSv1.2_2018 security policy
- Origin domain name is `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
- Minimum origin SSL protocol is TLSv1
- Origin protocol policy is HTTPS Only
- HTTP Port 80
- HTTPS Port 443
- Viewer Protocol Policy is Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
- Allowed HTTP Methods are GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE

Any help would greatly be appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem Please look at this (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-requirements.html).. One of the domain names in the certificate must match the domain name that you specify for Origin Domain Name. If no domain name matches, CloudFront returns HTTP status code 502 (Bad Gateway) to the viewer.